# Android Auto: My App doesn't play audio

Tags: android, audio, android-service, android-auto

I'm implementing Android Auto support for my app, but it is not working properly. I've followed Google's documentation and some tutorials, but the audio is not working. The controls, album art, artist name, etc., all appear just fine.

**Strange behaviour: After running Spotify app through the Auto emulator and playing a song, if I go to my app and Try to play the audio, it works!**

Here's the service class I've implemented:

```
/**
 * Created by FelipeRRM on 8/13/2016.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class AutoMediaBrowserService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {

    private static final String CURRENT_MEDIA_POSITION = "media_position_key";
    private static final int PLAY = 1;
    private static final int PAUSE = 2;
    private static final int BUFFERING = 3;
    private static final int CONNECTING = 4;
    private static final int STOPPED = 5;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    private static final String MY_MEDIA_ROOT_ID = "meuiddaraiz";
    MediaSessionCompat mSession;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "session tag");
        setSessionToken(mSession.getSessionToken());

        // Set a callback object to handle play control requests, which
        // implements MediaSession.Callback
        mSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onPlay() {
                super.onPlay();
                playMedia( PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( getApplicationContext() ).getInt( CURRENT_MEDIA_POSITION, 0 ), null );
            }

            //This is called when the pause button is pressed, or when onPlayFromMediaId is called in
            //order to pause any currently playing media
            @Override
            public void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
               setMediaPlaybackState(PAUSE);
                pauseMedia();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStop() {
                super.onStop();
                setMediaPlaybackState(STOPPED);
                if( mediaPlayer != null ) {
                    pauseMedia();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AutoMediaBrowserService.this).edit().putInt( CURRENT_MEDIA_POSITION,
                            0 ).commit();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayFromMediaId(String mediaId, Bundle extras) {
                super.onPlayFromMediaId(mediaId, extras);
                mSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                        .putText(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, "primeira musica")
                        .putText(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "Joãozinho das Rezas")
                        .putText(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_GENRE, "Gospel")
                        .putText(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI, "http://70.38.6.72/~vivafe/web/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/01.jpg")
                        .build()
                );
                playMedia(0, mediaId);
            }



            @Override
            public void onPlayFromSearch(String query, Bundle extras) {
                super.onPlayFromSearch(query, extras);
            }

        });

        mSession.setActive(true);
    }

    private void setMediaPlaybackState( int state ) {
        PlaybackStateCompat playbackState = null;
        switch (state) {
            case PLAY:
            playbackState = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                    .setActions( PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS )
                    .setState( PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 1 )
                    .build();
                break;

            case PAUSE:
            playbackState = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                    .setActions( PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE )
                    .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED, 0, 1)
                    .build();
                break;

            case BUFFERING:
                playbackState = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                        .setActions( PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP )
                        .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_BUFFERING, 0, 1)
                        .build();
                break;

            case CONNECTING:
                playbackState = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                        .setActions( PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP )
                        .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_CONNECTING, 0, 1)
                        .build();
                break;

            case STOPPED:
                playbackState = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                        .setActions( PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_FROM_MEDIA_ID )
                        .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_STOPPED, 0, 1)
                        .build();
                break;
        }
        mSession.setPlaybackState( playbackState );
    }

    private void playMedia(final int position, String id ) {
        setMediaPlaybackState(BUFFERING);
        if( mediaPlayer != null )
            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        else
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://70.38.6.72/~vivafe/web/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Mateus-01.mp3");
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                if( position > 0 )
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo( position );
                setMediaPlaybackState(PLAY);
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int state, int extra) {
                switch (state){
                    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START:{
                        Log.d("MediaPlayer","StartBuffer");
                        setMediaPlaybackState(BUFFERING);
                        break;
                    }

                    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END:{
                        Log.d("MediaPlayer","EndBuffer");
                        setMediaPlaybackState(PLAY);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int state, int extra) {
                Log.e("MediaPlayer Error", String.valueOf(state));
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    private void pauseMedia() {
        if( mediaPlayer != null ) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( this ).edit().putInt( CURRENT_MEDIA_POSITION,
                    mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() ).commit();
        }
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public BrowserRoot onGetRoot(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new BrowserRoot(MY_MEDIA_ROOT_ID, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadChildren(@NonNull String parentId, @NonNull Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>> result) {
        List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem> mediaItems = new ArrayList<>();
        // Check if this is the root menu:

        if (parentId.equals(MY_MEDIA_ROOT_ID)) {
            mediaItems.add(new MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem(new MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder().setMediaId("iddopastor").setTitle("Pastor").build(), MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem.FLAG_BROWSABLE));
        } else if (parentId.equals("iddopastor")) {
            mediaItems.add(new MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem(new MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder().setMediaId("iddopastor2").setTitle("Pastor 2").build(), MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem.FLAG_BROWSABLE));

            // examine the passed parentMediaId to see which submenu we're at,
            // and put the children of that menu in the mediaItems list
        }
        else if(parentId.equals("iddopastor2")){
            mediaItems.add(new MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem(new MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder().setMediaId("genealogia")
                    .setTitle("Tomé filho de José")
                    .setMediaUri(Uri.parse("http://70.38.6.72/~vivafe/web/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Mateus-01.mp3"))
                    .setIconUri(Uri.parse("http://70.38.6.72/~vivafe/web/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/01.jpg"))
                    .build(), MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem.FLAG_PLAYABLE));
        }
        result.sendResult(mediaItems);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mSession.release();
        if( mediaPlayer != null ) {
            pauseMedia();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( this ).edit().putInt( CURRENT_MEDIA_POSITION,
                    0 ).commit();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Sorry for the long code, but the erro might be anywhere on this class!

I've also put this on my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
        android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.notification.SmallIcon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />

<service android:name=".Auto.AutoMediaBrowserService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=
                "android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

And I have this on my res\xml\automotive_app_desc.xml:

```
<automotiveApp>
<uses name="media" />
</automotiveApp>
```

Comment: Lately, playing audio in the emulator has been buggy sometimes it cuts out, I had same sort of issues, it's not your code.

Comment: @ShadowGod, how come Spotify's app work flawlesly in the emulator? This is so strange... It seems as if I'm not starting or initializing something I should, because when I go from Spotify's app to mine it works, otherwise the audio will never play!

Comment: Can you try it on a real device? I guess that would be hard if you don't have a car with Android Auto, lol I don't even know if you can do that .. anyway all I can say is that I had issues with the emulator not playing audio but on a real device (phone) it was fine ... Also, as with all audio playing apps make sure you're following audio focus rules: https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html .. other than that you'd need someone more advanced than me to look the code over, nothing stands out to me as an error

Comment: @ShadowGod, I don't have a real Android Auto device here, unfortunately. I'll try to do the audio focus thing!

Comment: @ShadowGod, actually the audio focus thing did the trick! Thank you very much! Though very interesting to see that none of the offcial examples ever mention about it being such an important part!

Answer (score 0):

I think I might had the same problem. try to request audio focus before you start playing. I can hear my music on the desktop head unit